# Sharepoint 2007 query utilizing extensive resources

Tags: sql-server, database, sharepoint

While on SQL Server activitity monitor, I noticed I had the following query hog up a lot of resources in terms of logical read and CPU Usage. Anyone know what this query does and how I can disable it?

```
IF EXISTS 
            (SELECT * FROM MSSCrawlContent 
            WHERE CrawlID IN 
                (SELECT CrawlID FROM MSSCrawlHistory
                 WHERE CrawlID <> @CrawlID
                 AND (Status = @CRAWL_STATUS_START OR Status = @CRAWL_STATUS_PAUSE))             
            AND StartAddressID IN
                (SELECT StartAddressID FROM MSSCrawlContent
                WHERE CrawlID = @CrawlID))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that's the content crawler that crawls through the Sharepoint sites and indexes documents. It's a pretty intense process. I've had to coordinate with my Sharepoint admin to have them set the content crawl process for off hours.

As an aside, this process also generates some ridiculous logs. Part of working with the Sharepoint admin led us to some articles that suggested a that we set the recovery model to simple and set the backup to occur sometime after the crawl completes on the  [Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_{GUID}] database. AutoShrink was also recommended (though that's very non-standard) because the db and log file will grow wildly out of control. I still haven't decided on whether or not to do this second change, but the first helped us immensely.

Comment: You were right about the content crawler utilizing that query. I was able to use the directions in the following link to schedule the crawl at a more appropriate time  - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263373(v=office.12).aspx